# SSRS drill through report

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating two ssrs reports. First report lists the names of all of the **ELEMENTS** in the dataset.

so, when you click on any of the element of the first report then second report should display definition of only that element.

second report's dataset contains definition of all the elements. so basically when you click on the element name from first report, it should pass that name to the second report.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click on your TextBox with the field, and select the Action property
2. Select the "Go to report" action, specify your subreport
3. "Add" a paramter, and pass the field's value to it

Something like `=Parameters!YourElements.Value`

See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159847(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I tried this. So, I added a parameter ElementCode_Code and specified a value for it. But, I am getting an error. Please see screenshots attached in original post.

Comment: I get an error "an attempt was made to set a report parameter 'ElementCode_Code' that is not defined in this report "

Comment: Are you sure you have parameter "ElementCode_Code" defined in the report?. It looks like your report does not have a parameter named "ElementCode_Code". To add this parameter, while viewing your report, go to Report->Report Parameters then add the parameter "ElementCode_Code".

Comment: This answer should work unless you are doing something different. Please post the relevant screen shots.

Comment: I can't post any images unless I achieve 10 reputations. I  have defined a parameter 'ElementCode_Code' under parameters and same parameter I am passing through 'Action' section of my report. but I am getting an error "an attempt was made to set a report parameter 'ElementCode_Code' that is not defined in this report". Please help me.

Comment: Thanks, I did everything right, but I didn't added a same parameter on the second(drill-through) report.After adding the same parameter on second report it worked. thanks a lot